# countdown timer begin first tick after 3 seconds

Tags: java, android

I have a count down timer that must run for 30 seconds with a tick interval of 3 seconds.
But it seems the first tick happens as soon as the timer starts. I want the first tick to happen after 3 seconds.
And the next tick every 3 seconds. How can I do this?

Here is my code -

```
if (!timerRunning && timer == null) {
            timer = new CountDownTimer(300000, 3000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {
                    timerRunning = true;
                    Log.e(TAG,"Tick every 3 seconds");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    timerRunning = false;
                }
            }.start();
        }
```

Comment: `if(l==3000) { timerRunning = true; } else { //do something }`

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is using a handler like below:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 3000ms
  }
}, 3000);
```

So this code can help you:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if (!timerRunning && timer == null) {
        timer = new CountDownTimer(300000, 3000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                timerRunning = true;
                Log.e(TAG,"Tick every 3 seconds");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timerRunning = false;
            }
        }.start();
    }
  }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: How can i stop it?

Comment: After 30 seconds (after timer starts) your timer will be stopped automatically. If you want to stop it earlier you can do it by timer.cancel();